# Looping functions python

Tags: python, list, loops, functional-programming

I have a function f(x), that I would like to apply to every item in a dictionary or list.

I remembered from the Pandas library, you can apply a function to a whole data frame in place. Is it possible to do this in normal python code?

Is there any way of simplifying the following?

```
d = {1:'item1','2':'item2','a':'item1','b':'random'}
f = lambda x: 'SomeValue' if x == 'item1' else x
for key in d.keys():
    d[key] = f(d[key])
```

Edit: 
I know `d = {key: f(value) for key,value in d.iteritems()}` but doesn't this still loop over all keys? 
Does this even make the loop slower since it is storing key & value?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a *simpler* way, or a way that is more computationally efficient?

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are assigning a `lambda` to a name (`f = lambda ...`) then there is no point using `lambda` - just define a function instead.

Comment: Both actually, the most computationally efficient and also the shortest code. I can use each method when necessary in that case.

Comment: Is there anything bad with using a lambda to shorten the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
d = {k: f(v) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

But this will create a new dict (rather than modifying the original).  In many cases this is what you want anyway.  (This is also how it works in pandas in most cases.)  There is no direct shortcut for modifying the values of the original dict in place.

From your edit, it sounds like you're concerned about the performance.  The basic Python types don't have the sort of vectorized operations provided by pandas and numpy (i.e., operating on the whole structure 'at once").  That's why numpy was created.  If performance is you goal, you should benchmark both approaches on realistic data for your use case.  In general, the operations themselves are faster in numpy if they are numeric operations that can be vectorized, but the creation of new numpy arrays (including operations that change their size, such as `append`) is comparatively slow.

Comment: In terms of memory, does it create the dictionary in the same memory space or does it remove the original and create a new one in memory? Or does create two entries in memory but unlinks the first?

Comment: @alexmcf: No, since the old dictionary will still exist until after the new one is assigned.  If the old one is no longer referenced, it will (eventually) be garbage-collected, but this will depend on whether there were any references to it besides your variable `d`.